# Как открыть PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5

Где находится exe файл для создания программы на PyGt?

Comment: Если вы имете ввиду дизайнер PyQt, то вам сюда С:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\

Comment: p.s Исправьте PyGt на PyQt в вопросе. Кнопка "Править"